# Cannot install google play services

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google, google-play-services

My HTC Desire S (Rooted and installed with Sabsa Prime ROM) have Avast Mobile Security as antivirus. Recently I was given a free Premium Security code by Avast. But I'm unable to update the code on to Avast as the following error message is shown.

"Google Play Services, which some of your applications rely on,is not supported by your device. Kindly contact the manufacturer for assistance".

I have tried installing the Play Services via Google Play Store as well as manual apk installation, but still it doesn't work. Manual apk installation did say the installation success, but even after rebooting, the Avast says the same error message. HTC Desire S does support Play services, as said by Google Support page. Please help!!

Comment: Have you tried installing the gApps specific to your ROM. I have no experience with Sabsa Prime but this helped with CM

Comment: Yes I did. But it didn't work..